# onClick event is not getting triggered on React Popover (Material UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Please assume Popover is already opened. And now I want, If user click on popover its should redirect it to "getBikes".
I have tried `onClick` on Popover, Also tried adding event on div. But still the click event on Popover is not working.

```
 <Popover
  onClick={e => {
  window.location.href = "/getBikes/"
  }}
  open={eventOpen}
  anchorEl={eventAchor}
  className={classes.popoverreact}

  >
      <div onClick ={this.onClickHandle}>
      <Typography>
        {eventBike.name}
      </Typography>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hard to see without `Popover` implementation, but have you defined `onClick` prop in this component and bind the value to an html element (like what you did for divs)? `onClick` is not defined automatically to React components when you create them, but is a replacement of `onclick` html attribute https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: @MaximeHelen  no I did not defined any prop for onClick. Please can you guide me on that.

Comment: I posted a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to define  `onClick` callback as prop in `Popover`:

```
const Popover = ({ open, anchorEl, className, onClick }) => (<div id="wrapper" onClick={{onClick}}>
...
</div>);
```

`onClick` is the react way to bind click callbacks to HTML Elements

A component is an abstracted notion to wrap several HTML elements or code logics. Therefore applying a `onClick` prop by assuming the event will be listened by default by a container that could be empty or define only logic doesn't make sense

Here is the [doc](http://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for more info